# Opera dragonfly script debugger annoyances

Tags: javascript, opera, javascript-debugger, opera-dragonfly

Is there a way to reduce or filter the number of scripts shown in script debugger? With Chrome it just shows the file containing the scripts instead of every single script block.

Also, when I set debug points on an inline script and go through the code the page reloads and selects the first script in the drop down. I then have to reset all my break points.

Overall Opera seems to be pretty cool, just need to find a way to work around these few annoyances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any way around these at the moment. My experience with Dragonfly is pretty similar... Overall it's great but there's a couple of small annoyances :)

You could try [filing a ticket](https://github.com/operasoftware/dragonfly/issues/new) to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a filter in the Scripts dropdown now, should make it easier to get where you want to go. On breakpoints, I'm not sure what you mean. They shouldn't disappear unless you close Dragonfly or change the debug context. You can always see all Breakpoints and navigate directly to them from the Breakpoints panel on the left.

If not, then yes, please file a bug.